# Checkbox no Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um formulário  com algumas informações de cadastro como tarefa no meu trabalho de estágio.

Essas informações devem ser impressas no Console, o problema está em 3 caixas de checkbox que eu não consigo exibir a opção selecionada no console.

html.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <h5><strong>Serviço:</strong></h5>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
      Suporte
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
      Desenvolvimento
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">
      Infraestrutura
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function enviar() {

    //Variaveis que recebem valor dos inputs e depois são atribuidas ao JSON
    var data = $("#inputData").val();
    var nome = $("#inputNome").val();
    var cep = $("#inputCep").val();
    var endereco = $("#inputEndereco").val();
    var cidade = $("#inputCidade").val();
    var estado = $("#inputState").val();
    var bairro = $("#inputBairro").val();
    var cnpj = $("#txtCnpj").val();
    var preço = $("#inputPreco").val();
    var codigo = $("#txtCodigo").val();
    var servico = $("#defaultCheck1").val();

    //checkbox
    var formValue = {
        data: data,
        name: nome,
        endereço: endereco,
        cep: cep,
        cidade: cidade,
        estado: estado,
        bairro: bairro,
        cnpj: cnpj,
        preço: preço,
        codigo: codigo,

    };

    console.log(formValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa checar a propriedade `checked` e não `value`.

Como está usando jQuery, é possível usar o método `prop`.

```js
$('#bt').on('click', function () {
  const c = $('#defaultCheck2').prop('checked')
  console.log(c)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="defaultCheck2"><br>
<button id="bt">Testar</button>
```

Comment: funcionou!! e como posso ao inés de retornar "True" no console ele retornar o texto do checkbox ??

Comment: @ThiagoMedeirosdeLima Ótimo. Acho que seria um problema para outra pergunta, porque envolve outras operações daí. Aliás, se a resposta solucionou seu problema, você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **V** no lado esquerdo dela (apenas uma por pergunta). E bem-vindo ao [pt.so].

Comment: Muito Obrigado pelo apoio, sou novo no desenvolvimento e no Stack Overflow!